# How to run powershell quietly from registry key?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, registry

I've added an option to copy a proper UNC path to the context menu of all directories via PowerShell.

Edit:

I didn't mention that I'm actually using two different keys: One to copy the UNC of the current directory, and one to copy it from a different directory. I didn't think it would make a difference, but it does.

End Edit

Currently, the key value is as follows:

```
powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Command . <path I have to censor>\Save-To-Clipboard.ps1 \"%L%\"
```

Expected behaviour:
The PowerShell script is run quietly.

Actual behaviour:
A PowerShell Window pops up and closes itself.

The same thing happens with cmd.
I've tried using a VBS wrapper as well, but it needs the current path as an argument, which I can't figure out how to do. Simply putting it after the filename as you would in the command line results  in the error:

> This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this
> action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create
> an association in the Default Apps settings page.

Key value here:

```
<path I have to censor>\ClunkyWrapper.vbs \"%L%\"
```

Admittedly, this is my first time running a command from a registry key, and I can't seem to find any resources about this topic. (I might just not know what exactly to google for.) So I would be thankful for more general information on how to run commands from registry keys as well.

Comment: `cscript.exe ClunkyWrapper.vbs` ?

Comment: Right when I was writing my own answer. Wscript.exe works better for me, since cscript.exe still seems to want to open a window.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way.
First of all, apparently whether you need to use %L% or %V% depends on the key. I can't tell you why, unfortunately.
That solves the error message of the VBA script, but it still wouldn't run like this.
So I then used wscript.exe, and it finally worked.

```
wscript.exe <secret path>\ClunkyWrapper.vbs "%V%"
```